# Is there a better way to pass multiple props down to n children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently working a group project and I've been looking over the code the group wrote and I'm curious if there is a better way to pass props to n children components that change the state of the top-level App component.

currently we have something like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <header className="navBar">
      // NavBar is an example for the question
      <NavBar
        showSplash={this.state.showSplash}
        displayAllSearchResults={this.displayAllSearchResults}
        searchBarDisplay={this.state.showCard}
        updateResults={this.updateResults}
        selectResult={this.selectResult}
        searchResults={this.state.searchResults}
        showSuggestions={this.state.showSuggestions}
      />
    </header>
    <section className="App">
      <article className="mainContent">{card}</article>
    </section>
    <div className="appBackground" />
  </div>
);
```

All of these methods (which there are probably too many) are being passed into the `NavBar` component that itself is composed with a `SearchBar` component which also needs that giant block passed into it in order to change the state all the way back at the top-level `App`. This *feels* wrong, is there a solution or better approach to passing all these props down?

Comment: In my projects I pass props as Abdelkarim explained in his answer if it's just down to a child's child. If it happens to be a depth >= 3 children then I either refactor or use React contexts to access props from the hierarchy tree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `spread` operator like this :

```
<NavBar  {...this.state} />
```

It will pass you state properties as props to the navbar.

In you Navbar component, you can get the value of `showSplash` in state from `props.showSplash`

If you want to pass the data into a child component of Navbar, you can do something like this :

```
<ChildComponent {...props} /> // if Navbar is a functional component

<ChildComponent {...this.props} /> // if Navbar is a stateful component
```

Reference:

[Spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)

Here is a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9aq5qc?) for illustration.

Comment: You can but I wouldn't. Spreading props like this can get messy quickly as when the container needs more props that are irrelevant to NavBar you'd have to separate them making it harder to think about what exactly NavBar is receiving. 
There's also a chance that you'd forget to filter out the unneeded props and you end up with some children receiving props they don't care about. 
If other parts of the container don't care about those state values, I'd 'move state down' - wrap it in a component that encapsulates it together with the children. This way you avoid whole App rerenders.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a data to be accessible by all the child components, then you have following options:

- [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or state management library like [flux](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-to-know-flux-the-react-js-architecture) etc.

Or you could follow @Abdelkarim EL AMEL answer if that soughts out you issue for now.I would suggest take a look at the above mentioned options and if setting a global state which can be accessed anywhere in the app helps you to not send prop to each component explicitly. I would prefer to use a global state for variable which are common and needs to be accessed by all the child of the root app.

For example a button component to change the theme of the app. It changes the state of the root app and is accessible by every component.

Comment: There's a new state management library that is so easy to understand especially for beginners. It's called MST(Mobx-State-Tree). Probably one of his best option if ever he decides to use state manager. Redux and flux I think, is a bit too complicated to set up especially for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is actually entirely OK, and would recommend leaving it.

If you don't like seeing it itemized in the return of the render method you could keep them all in an object called navbarprops and just spread that in. I still prefer it as is though!